# How to set the log level for an imported module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-import

Write your code with a nice logger

```
import logging

def init_logging():
     logFormatter = logging.Formatter("[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s::%(module)s::%(funcName)s() %(message)s")
     rootLogger = logging.getLogger()
     LOG_DIR = os.getcwd() + '/' + 'logs'
     if not os.path.exists(LOG_DIR):
          os.makedirs(LOG_DIR)
     fileHandler = logging.FileHandler("{0}/{1}.log".format(LOG_DIR, "g2"))
     fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
     rootLogger.addHandler(fileHandler)
     rootLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
     consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
     consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
     rootLogger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
     return rootLogger

logger = init_logging()
```

works as expected. Logging using `logger.debug("Hello! :)")` logs to file and console.

In a second step you want to **import** an **external module which is also logging using logging module**:

1. Install it using `pip3 install pymisp` (or any other external module)
2. Import it using `from pymisp import PyMISP` (or any other external module)
3. Create an object of it using `self.pymisp = PyMISP(self.ds_model.api_url, self.ds_model.api_key, False, 'json')` (or any other...)

What now happens is, that **every debug log output from the imported module is getting logged** to the log file and the console. **The question now is, how to set a different (higher) log level for the imported module.**

Comment: if google brings you here, it's better to use `logging.getLogger('modulename').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` instead of directly manipulating a logging object from a module.

Answer (score 23):

The most generic method is to retrieve the logger by the name of the imported module as follows:

```
import logging
import some_module_with_logging
logging.getLogger("some_module_with_logging").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

With this approach you can also set the log level of submodules by specifying them using *dot* notation:

```
logging.getLogger("some_module_with_logging.submodule").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

This should work for third-party-packages as they normally stick to the convention of using a named logger with a name according to the module name:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Another option (though not recommended if the generic method above works) is to extract the module's logger variable and customize it to your needs. Most third-party modules store it in a module-level variable called `logger` or `_log`. In your case:

```
import logging    
import pymisp

pymisp.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# code of module goes here
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this case `{AttributeError}'PyMISP' object has no attribute 'logger'`

Comment: It's because of your import. Use `import pymisp` instead of (or addtional to) `from pymisp import PyMISP`

Comment: And then use `pymisp.logger.setLevel(...)` instead of `PyMISP.logger.setLevel(...)`.

Comment: Edited to match the general case.

Comment: Some modules use _log instead of logger (e.g. matplotlib).

Comment: If `logger` or `_log` does not exist for a library, an alternative is to do: ```logging.getLogger("imported_module_name").setLevel(logging.WARNING)```

Answer (score -1):

A colleague of mine helped with this question:

1. Get a named logger `yourLogger = logging.getLogger('your_logger')`
2. Add a filter to each handler prevents them to print/save other logs than yours

   ```
   for handler in logging.root.handlers:
       handler.addFilter(logging.Filter('your_logger'))
   ```

Comment: With this approach you don't set a higher log level, but suppress the logs of the modules totally.